# transform data with multiple fields in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have some data in the following way:

```
(102,(727,103,895))

(102,(105,255))
```

anyone knows how to transform these data to the following way in pig?

```
(102,727)

(102,103)

(102,895)

(102,105)

(102,255)
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you have ? How you read the data ? What issue you are seeing ? You can think of reading the second element as a tuple of ints and then use FLATTEN to get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

Use FLATTEN().Assuming you have relation B with two fields

```
C = foreach B generate B.$0,FLATTEN(B.$1);
DUMP C;
```

[image]

Comment: get this result:  (102,727,103,895),

(102,105,255)

Comment: raw data is huge. Suppose after some steps, I dump B and got(102,(727,103,895)),(102,(105,255)), then I use the script you provide, finally got  (102,727,103,895), (102,105,255) .....

Comment: @Summer Remove the TOBAG and just use FLATTEN.I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank. I will try. BTW, what is the pig version you use?